# Distribute SQL_SSDT Code Snippets using vscontent (lang attribute error)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-snippets, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to distribute some SQL_SSDT Visual Studio code snippets using `.vsi` and `.vscontent` files, but I'm getting an error while installing:

> The .vscontent file either contains invalid attributes or specifies a code snippet for a programming language that is not installed.

The `.vscontent` file is based on the documentation provided by Microsoft [How to: Distribute Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242311.aspx)

The sample on this site is the following:

```
<VSContent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vscontent/2005">
    <Content>
        <FileName> </FileName>
        <DisplayName> </DisplayName>
        <Description> </Description>
        <FileContentType> </FileContentType>
        <ContentVersion>2.0</ContentVersion>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute name="lang" value=""/>
        </Attributes>
    </Content>
</VSContent>
```

My file looks like this:

```
<VSContent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vscontent/2005">
    <Content>
        <FileName>SSDTTest.snippet</FileName>
        <DisplayName>SSDTTest</DisplayName>
        <Description>SSDTTest</Description>
        <FileContentType>Code Snippet</FileContentType>
        <ContentVersion>1.0</ContentVersion>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute name="lang" value="SQL_SSDT"/>
        </Attributes>
    </Content>
</VSContent>
```

I'm using the value `SQL_SSDT` since this is the required value in the `.snippet` files (`<Code Language="SQL_SSDT">`).

The installation starts as expected (double clicking on the `.vsi` file), the VS Content Installer pops up, lists the included content. The error occurs after hitting `Finish`. (Installation starts, but the above error pops up after a few seconds.)

The snippet is working fine if I copy it to the default snippet folder for SSDT (`Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\SQL_SSDT\My Code Snippets`) or if I'm adding it via snippet manager in SSDT, but the `.vsi` installation fails using the above file.

Am I missing something?

Installed VS products on this box:

- SSDT
- SSDT-BI
- VS Express for Desktop (2012)

**Update**

I found the [XML schema reference for the `.vscontent` files (VS2012)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398097(v=vs.110).aspx), and it seems that the SQL_SSDT is not a valid value for the `Lang` attribute. It suggests that there are only four values available for the `lang` attribute. (`csharp`, `jsharp`, `vb`, `xml`).

Now the question is: Does SSDT add any extensions to this XML schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that VS Content Installer has no support for deploying SSDT code snippets. There is a posted [idea on visualstudio.uservoice.com](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4390727-support-for-deployment-code-snippets-for-sql-serve) which requests this feature, but it is still open.

I did not found any other resources related to this issue.

There is a possible workaround, which needs testing: You can create a PS/BAT which copies the snippet files into the VS's snippet folder for SSDT.